# React data after .Map

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to render the data from the Object data component in React JS.
I have an initial false state and toggle arrow function.
When I am clicking "+" my all item specifications are toggling, however, I would like to onClick to show only the clicked item specs. The fragment of the code is below: Any tips or help will be much appreciated.

```
const toggler = () => {
toggle ? setToggle(false): setToggle(true);
}


return (
const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false)

<Div1>
<Div2> 
    <TitleDiv>
        <h2>Please check out our fees below </h2>
    </TitleDiv>
</Div2>

<Div3>

    {Data.products.map((product) => {

    return(
        
    <Cont key= {product.id}>
        <Container> {product.name}<button onClick ={() =>{toggler}>+</button></Container>
        {toggle ? <Container2>{product.price} {product.quantity}<Container2>: null}
    </Cont>

        
    })}
</Div3>)   


<Div1>
export default Services
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using a single state here:

```
const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false)
```

and if a single state will change then definitely it will update all of its dependent row. So take this toggle state as `array` or `object` that will have a specific `value` or `key:value` for every entry in that data array and update that specific value for a specific row and use that specific value for toggle in that row.

**In easy words:** maintain an entry where you store the toggle state for each product

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have one single boolean value, it is not uniquely able to identify which product id is toggled

Instead of having aa boolean value for toggle, maintain an object map where you store the toggle state for each productId.

```
const [toggle, setToggle] = useState({});
const toggler = (productId) => {
    setToggle(prev => ({
        ...prev,
        [productId]: !Boolean(productId)
    }))

}

return (
   <Div1>
        <Div2> 
            <TitleDiv>
                <h2>Please check out our fees below </h2>
            </TitleDiv>
        </Div2>
    
    <Div3>
     {Data.products.map((product) => {
        return(   
          <Cont key= {product.id}>
            <Container> {product.name}<button onClick ={() =>{toggler(product.id)}>+</button></Container>
            {toggle[product.id] ? <Container2>{product.price} {product.quantity}<Container2>: null}
          </Cont>
        )})}
    </Div3>    
  <Div1>
)

...
export default Services
```